# How do I convert css selector path copied from Chrome to beautifulsoup obejct?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I've been trying to make a function that returns beautifulsoup object when css selector path copied from Chrome dev tool is given.

When I copy a element's css selector path from Chrome, it goes like:

```
body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.ColumnText2
```

If I want it to become a legit beautifulsoup object, I would manually parse it like

```
html = urlopen("https://someurl.com")

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

bs.body.find_all('table')[3].find_all('tbody')[0].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td', {'class': 'ColumnText2'})
```

But this is really clumsy and if I have to do it manually, there's no point in making a function. Is there some kind of built-in parser that can convert this css selector path to beautifulsoup object right away?

Comment: maybe look into [`soup.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) method which allows searching by css?

Comment: @politicalscientist Wow it just worked right away. I didn't even have to do anything. Maybe I should have searched more thoroughly. This solved my problem thanks. If you answer the question instead of commenting, I'll make sure to choose the answer.

Comment: Great! `.select` was a game changer for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** please try Select in Beautifulsoup**

```
html = urlopen("https://someurl.com")

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

name_tags=bs .select("body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.ColumnText2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Note also that Chrome will insert a `tbody` element in tables even if the source doesn't have it. Try removing the `> tbody` from your selector.

Comment: So true. That gave me pain in the past before I eventually found that out. Thanks for the input.